# Es posible crear servicios background netamente de flutter?

Tags: flutter

Buenas Noches amigos de flutter , mi idea es crear un servicio background pequeño donde cada 3 mins consulte un servicio, este servicio background lo tengo en una app nativa (tanto en android como en ios donde consume un servicio cada 3 mins) y funciona bien pero mi pregunta es si existe alguna manera de crear un servicio background donde se este ejecutando cada 3 mins y este llame a un servicio ya sea que este abierta o no la app no importa pero lo mas importante que sea de flutter o si hay algun paquete que me ayude en esto?, o si o si tendre que hacerlo por channel?
Muchas Gracias Amigos.

Comment: Revisa este package https://pub.dev/packages/worker_manager

Comment: Muchas Gracias diegoVeloper , por si acaso en tu canal no tienes algun video donde explique sobre Isolates en bajo nivel?  se que existe el Compute pero quisiera abajo nivel. Gracias.

Comment: Hmm no pero en este caso es necesario que uses plugins como ese que puse o codigo nativo